# Why $0.999$... isn't the largest number before 1?

Tags: number-systems

Why doesn't it called like that? It seems fair, $1$ called $1$ while $0.999$... being the largest number before $1$, and not called $1$ while not look like it is. Let's say it isn't, how would that number look like?

Comment: This has been asked many times before (e.g. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504309/is-0-9999-an-integer)).

Comment: This isn't duplicate, I show new argument.

Comment: The question is duplicate because it is based on the same fallacy : taking the symbolic representation of a number for the number itself. $2$ is the double of $1$ independently of the fact that in roman numerals $2$ is represented as $II$ while $1$ is represented as $I$; otherwise, we have to conclude that $IV$ is **not** the double of $II$.

Comment: This is like asking what is the last item in an infinite series

Answer (score 2):

$0.999999\ldots$ is exactly $1$. It is just another way of writing the number $1$, and is not less than $1$. You can prove this by subtracting $ 1 - 0.999999 \ldots $ and seeing that the answer is $0$. Alternatively, you can prove that there is no "largest number less than 1."

*Proof.* Note that for any fraction $\frac{p}{q}$ less than one, there is a slightly bigger fraction which is still less than one; in particular,  $\frac{p+q}{2q}$ is a fraction such that $\frac{p}{q} < \frac{p+q}{2q} < 1$. $\Box$

Comment: Alternatively: where $x=.999\dots$, $10x=9.999\dots=9+x$, so $9x=9$ so $x=1$.