# Is 0.999... irrational?

Tags: irrational-numbers

*Rational number - a number that can be represented as the quotient p/q of two integers such that q ≠ 0

-Britannica*

By that definition is any number which has the decimal part $.999...$ irrational?

Also, furthermore can we argue that 0.999..., a recurring decimal is in fact imaginary since we say it is =1 or ≈1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/11/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/504309/42969

Comment: It is not just approximate $1$ , it is exactly $1$. And this shows that it is even a natural number.

Comment: Irrational means that there is no period. Here we have the (aritifical) period $\bar 9$

Answer (score 0):

$0.999\ldots = 1\in\mathbb{Q}$